# Do you need to subscribe the Observable every time an API call is made?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a method `doGET` in `component.ts` being called when user clicks the button. Inside the `doGET` method I'm subscribing to the method called `getData` returning an observable in `service.ts`. But doesn't it gets subscribed each time I'm clicking the button or calling the `doGET` method? Is this the write way to make API calls in Angular ?
Here is my Angular component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [AppService]
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app works!';


    constructor(private service: AppService) {

    }

    doGET() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
            console.log('result is ', res);
        })

    }

}
```

Here is the Angular service code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

    apiRoot: string = "http://httpbin.org";

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getData(){
        let url = `${this.apiRoot}/get`;
        return this.http.get(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

component.ts

```
doGET() {
    this.service.getData()
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log('data', data);
            });
}
```

service.ts

```
apiRoot: string = "http://httpbin.org";
getData() {
        let url = `${this.apiRoot}/get`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is fine. Angular's Http Service will automatically unsubscribe *(destroys the subscription)* from the Observable once the call reaches it's conclusion.

However you may want to put in a peice of code that prevents multiple calls due to the user clicking 1000 times consecutively. Basic Example:

```
isGettingData = false;
doGET() {
    if(!this.isGettingData){
        this.isGettingData = true;
        this.service.getData().subscribe(res => {
            console.log('result is ', res);
            this.isGettingData = false;
        });
    }
}
```

If you are making your own Observable Variables/Services or some-such it's good practice to `.unsubscribe()` when the component is destroyed. Example:

```
myObserver: Observable<Array<any>>;
doGET() {
    this.myObserver= this.route.params.subscribe(params => {})
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.myObserver.unsubscribe();
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/6550273) has a detailed explanation